# How to prevent update of session expiration time for specific URL

Tags: python, session, flask

**Flask Version:**

```
>>> flask.__version__
'0.12.2'
```

I don't want to update the expiration time for a certain URL.
Currently, I use the following method for setting session expiration time:

```
session.permanent = true
app.permanent_session_lifetime = timedelta(minutes=int(10))
```

I have a status page which auto-refreshes every minute using an ajax method to get only the data.
I don't want to reset the session expiration time in this case.
Is there any way to do so?

**Edit:**

**My Code so far:**

```
from datetime import timedelta
from flask import Flask
from flask import session

APP = Flask(__name__, static_url_path='', static_folder='templates')

def create_user_session(user_accountid, auth_token):
    session['token'] = auth_token
    session['user_accountid'] = user_accountid

def update_session():
    session.permanent = True
    APP.permanent_session_lifetime = timedelta(minutes=10)
    session.modified = True

@APP.route('/batch_status', methods=['GET'])
def view_status():
    create_user_session(1, "****")
    update_session()
    return "Session Change"

@APP.route('/batch_status_json', methods=['GET'])
def retrieve_status():
    return "Session No Change"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    APP.secret_key = "My Precious Key"
    APP.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True, port=8000)
```

I don't want to change the session expiration time on `batch_status_json` call but it automatically changes when called.

**Edit2:**

**monitor_controller.py:**

```
from datetime import timedelta
from flask import Flask
from flask import session
from status import RETRIEVE_STATUS

APP = Flask(__name__, static_url_path='', static_folder='templates')

APP.register_blueprint(RETRIEVE_STATUS)
def create_user_session(user_accountid, auth_token):
    session['token'] = auth_token
    session['user_accountid'] = user_accountid

def update_session():
    session.permanent = True
    APP.permanent_session_lifetime = timedelta(minutes=10)
    session.modified = True

@APP.route('/batch_status', methods=['GET'])
def view_status():
    create_user_session(1, "****")
    update_session()
    return "Session Change"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    APP.secret_key = "My Precious Key"
    APP.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True, port=8000)
```

**status.py:**

```
from flask import Blueprint

RETRIEVE_STATUS = Blueprint('retrieve_status', __name__)
@RETRIEVE_STATUS.route('/batch_status_json', methods=['GET'])
def retrieve_status():
    return "Session No Change"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cookies are set if the session is marked modified OR if the `SESSION_REFRESH_EACH_REQUEST` option is set.  By default the option is True.

In your Flask config try setting

```
SESSION_REFRESH_EACH_REQUEST = False
```

From the documentation:

> SESSION_REFRESH_EACH_REQUEST
>
> Control whether the cookie is sent with
>   every response when session.permanent is true. Sending the cookie
>   every time (the default) can more reliably keep the session from
>   expiring, but uses more bandwidth. Non-permanent sessions are not
>   affected.
>
> Default: True

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:**

One other option is to use [`Blueprints`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/blueprints/) to separate your endpoints into different and autonomous apps:

1. Separate your "polling" (`retrieve_status()`) method in a blueprint.
2. Register the blueprint to your `APP`: `APP.register_blueprint(your_blue_print)`

Now your `retrieve_status()` method is separate from the `APP` methods and the `@before_request` doesn't get triggered when you call it.

Further reading on blueprints:

- http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/blueprints/ (official documentation)
- https://danidee10.github.io/2016/11/20/flask-by-example-8.html (tutorial-like)
- http://nullege.com/codes/search/flask.Blueprint.before_request (You can even create a `before_request` for your blueprint)

---

As I see it you have 2 options:

1. Use `session.modified=True` explicitly only inside the views, you want:

   ```
   from flask import session

   def update_session():
       session.permanent = True
       app.permanent_session_lifetime = timedelta(minutes=10)
       session.modified = True

   @app.route('/batch_status', methods=['GET'])
   def view_status():
       ...
       Do stuff
       ...    
       update_session()
       return "Session Change"
   ```

   and remove the session setup part of your `before_request()` method
2. Modify `before_request()` method to exclude the `retrieve_status` endpoint:

   ```
   @APP.before_request
   def before_request():
       ...
       Do stuff
       ...
       if (request.endpoint != 'retrieve_status'):
           session.permanent = True
           app.permanent_session_lifetime = timedelta(minutes=10)
           session.modified = True
   ```

Comment: Hi Sorry for removing my comment. I removed it since I wanted to comment after testing your result. After applying your suggestion the same issue still persists. Please find the updated script. Still the session expiry time changes `when visiting the batch_status_json`

Comment: @The6thSense Did you try the first option? I added another probable solution (highly recommended) using blueprints. Check it out!

Comment: Hi I tried both the first and second solution neither of them worked. I will try the blueprint method and let you know

Comment: Hi I also tried BluePrint but it also did not help. I am using flasks modules session and not flask-session hope this helps.

Comment: @The6thSense Do me a favor and test the following: Pass every endpoint and the `@before_request` as a `@RETRIEVE_STATUS.before_request` to the blueprint. Delete the `retrieve_status` from there and add it back to the `APP`.

Comment: Sorry John I didn't get you there? Could you please brief it?

Comment: @The6thSense Pass every endpoint except the `view_status` to a blueprint  (assume the name`my_blueprint`) and pass your `before_request()` method under a `@my_blueprint.before_request` decorator. Then connect the blueprint to your app and try again.

Comment: Hi John the other solution worked. Thanks for helping :).

Comment: @The6thSense ok happy coding :)